# Two launcher activities on android tv

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

Is it possible to have multiple launcher activities on android tv like on mobile android? I've tried to declare two activities with intent filters like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

but it doesn't work. I see two icons but they launch the same activity. Thanks in advance!